# How to attach vue event on dynamic element in methods section of vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In html table row, based on condition, need to update the row with SPAN or NA as below. But, vue onclick is unable to get work.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
onSelect:function(row){
           if(row["id"] > 10) {
              row["data"]= '<span v-on:click="onclick">Process</span>'
           }
           else {
                row["data"]= 'NA';
             }
    },
    onclick() {
       //do operations
    console.log('click');
    }
  }
})
```

How above click event can be work.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Vue is not designed to have the DOM manipulated by injecting elements in this way, theres likely a far easier/suitable way of solving your problem.

Comment: basically, on change of selection in dropdown, want to update the tabluar form 's row with injected SPAN (with vue click event).

Answer (score 2):

vue offers the [conditional-rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) api- where you can use `v-if` to render or not an element in your template. (in vue, you shouldn't create elements manually)

there you go:
https://jsfiddle.net/efrat19/9kobn6xt/24/

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  isClicked:false,
    companies: [
      { name: 'Alfreds Futterkiste',contact: 'Maria Anders',country:'Germany'},
      { name: 'companyZ',contact: 'efrat',country:'Israel'},
      { name: 'Ernst Handel',contact: 'bkjb',country:'USA'},
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    onClick: function(){
        this.isClicked = true;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

span {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.8/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>HTML Table</h2>
<button @click="onClick()">click me to insert a span to every column!</button>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr v-for="company in companies">
    <td>{{company.name}}</td>
    <td>{{company.contact}}</td>
    <td>{{company.country}}
    <span v-if="isClicked">i only exist after click!</span></td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
</div>
```